# R, Python: install packages on rpy2

Tags: python, r, import, package

I'm using `R` in my Python script through the `rpy2` library and I need a [package](http://dirichletreg.r-forge.r-project.org) that is not in the default installation of R.  How can I install it?

```
install.packages("DirichletReg", repos="http://r-forge.r-project.org")
```

won't work.

On Python:

```
>>> install.packages("DirichletReg", repos="http://r-forge.r-project.org") 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'install' is not defined
```

And from R:

```
> install.packages("DirichletReg", repos="http://r-forge.r-project.org")
Installing package(s) into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning message:
In getDependencies(pkgs, dependencies, available, lib) :
  package ‘DirichletReg’ is not available (for R version 2.14.1)
```

Answer (score -4, accepted):

How about this

```
>>> import rpy2.interactive as r
>>> r.importr("utils")
>>> package_name = "DirichletReg"
>>> r.packages.utils.install_packages(package_name)
```

Comment: Doesn't work anymore.  See Aaron's answer, which works as of now.

Answer (score 49):

Ricardo's answer no longer works.

To install from Python, we can use the `utils.install_packages` function:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
utils = importr('utils')
```

(That `utils` package is the `R.utils` package whose pdf documentation can be found here: https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=R.utils - or, more directly here, is the more verbose `install.packages` function documentation that we use: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/install.packages. It is renamed to `install_packages` in Python because the `.` is not part of a legal Python name as it is in R.)

Next, you need to decide which repo to get the package from.

You can declare the repo when calling  `utils.install_packages` with the `repos` argument:

```
utils.install_packages('DirichletReg', repos="https://cloud.r-project.org")
```

Or you can set the mirror before calling `utils.install_packages` with

```
utils.chooseCRANmirror(ind=1) # select the first mirror in the list
```

or

```
utils.chooseBioCmirror(ind=1) # select the first mirror in the list
```

otherwise Python/R will attempt to launch the interactive mirror selector (which may or may not work with your setup).

And then, for a single package:

```
utils.install_packages('DirichletReg')
```

Or for multiple packages, pass it a character vector:

```
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import StrVector

package_names = ('ggplot2', 'hexbin')
utils.install_packages(StrVector(package_names))
```

These examples were adapted from [the rpy2 documentation](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-dev/html/robjects_rpackages.html#installing-removing-r-packages) and the `install.packages` documentation - and as of my last edit, the documentation still says to do this.

Comment: I prefer to give the 'repos' arg as well, since in jupyter notebook last time I tried the popup menu to choose a mirror didn't work: `utils.install_packages('gutenbergr', repos='https://cloud.r-project.org')`

Comment: This no longer works with rpy 3.5.5: `NotImplementedError: Conversion 'rpy2py' not defined for objects of type '<class 'rpy2.rinterface.SexpClosure'>'`

Answer (score 5):

When running `pytest`, Aaron's answer makes my Python hang and R keep giving error messages, probably because of this:

> Calling `install_packages()` without first choosing a mirror will require the user to interactively choose a mirror.

According to [rpy2 documentation](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/introduction.html#installing-packages), I used this which worked:

```py
from rpy2 import robjects
import rpy2.robjects.packages as rpackages

utils = rpackages.importr('utils')
utils.chooseCRANmirror(ind=1)
utils.install_packages("DirichletReg")
DirichletReg = rpackages.importr("DirichletReg")
```

Comment: I think this works under the condition that the package is already installed in R.

Comment: @LCheng Thank you, I did not test for the case where the package was not installed in R.