# rpy2 cannot find installed external R packages

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I've done this before (~1 year ago now), but want to use R again via rpy2. I've confirmed that I can load default packages when I do this:

```
from rpy2 import robjects
plot = robjects.r.get('plot')
```

Now, when I try to load an external package like so,

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
betareg = importr('betareg')
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-b1ed20534ab9>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Patrick/OneDrive/FIDS/betareg.py', wdir='C:/Users/Patrick/OneDrive/FIDS')

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 685, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 71, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "C:/Users/Patrick/OneDrive/FIDS/betareg.py", line 11, in <module>
    betareg = importr('betareg')

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\packages.py", line 438, in importr
    env = _get_namespace(rname)

RRuntimeError: Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called 'betareg'
```

I have `R_HOME`, `R_USER`, and `R_LIBS` system variables set to make sure R gets loaded and (hopefully) gets pointed to where the external packages are located. The same thing also happens when I set the `lib_loc` kwarg in `importr` as the path to the package folder. I can load the package via `library('betareg')` in R from command line with the same run arguments that r2py is using (--quiet, --no-save).

Am I missing anything here? How can I get set up so that I can load installed external packages?

#### Version Info

OS:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10240]
```

Python version:

```
Python 2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 28 2015, 16:44:52)
[MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

R version:

```
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16) -- "Full of Ingredients"
Copyright (C) 2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
```

rpy2 version:

```
>>>import rpy2
>>> rpy2.__version__
'2.6.3'
```

Comment: `lib_loc`is reported to the working (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33309057/reference-package-in-personal-library-from-rpy2). May be you have several R installed and the one rpy2 is binding to is not the one you'd like ?

Comment: I did recently install a new version during the time of my post. I'll have to check sometime when I get the chance.

Answer (score 7):

To use external R packages in Conda you will install these packages in Conda. If you install them from R you can't use them. To install (e.g. for dtw library) it do next like:

```
import rpy2.robjects.packages as r
utils = r.importr("utils")
package_name = "dtw"
utils.install_packages(package_name)
```

Output is:

```
rpy2.rinterface.NULL
```

Then you can use this package

```
import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri.activate()

# Set up our R namespaces
R = rpy2.robjects.r

DTW = importr('dtw')   # our package
```