# Reference package in personal library from rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I have just installed the MSwM package from CRAN into my personal library location via RStudio, and I am trying to call it from Python using rpy2. However, it is giving me this error:

```
rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error in loadNamespace(name) : 
there is no package called 'MSwM'
```

I have tried referencing the standard package and they have no problems loading. Here is my code in Python:

```
from rpy2.robjects import r
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

base=importr('base')
utils=importr('utils')
markov=importr('MSwM')
```

So, both **base** and **utils**  are properly loaded, but markov fails to load. Can anyone shed some light on how I can get packages in personal library location to run in rpy2?(btw my set up is in Windows 7)
Just a FYI the current environment set up is like this :
R_USER=xxx
R_HOME=C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.2

My personal library is in C:\Users\xxx\Documents\R\win-library\3.2 and I am able to get MSwM loaded and run in RStudio itself.

Answer (score 2):

Never mind.I found the answer as importr has the lib_loc parameter to specify the location of the package, so I am doing the following and it is working now:

```
markov=importr('MSwM',lib_loc = "C:/Users/xxx/Documents/R/win-library/3.2")
```