# rpy2 error load specific packages given right directory

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, rpy2

I have used rpy2 to call R package successfully in python. However, I just install elasticnet today in R and I checked I can load the library in R without problem, also the package name folder *elasticnet* is in my directory.

I want to do the same call as other packages using `importr`, but it keeps giving me error message:

> Error in loadNamepace(name): there is no package called 'elasticnet'.

But I have go to that address and actually see the package, also in R I can see that package is installed. Anyone know how to solve this problem?

This is how I called other packages in python, for example the `pls` package:

```
import rpy2
import rpy2.robjects as ro
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

utils = importr("utils")
d = {'print.me': 'print_dot_me', 'print_me': 'print_uscore_me'}

pls = importr('pls', robject_translations = d, lib_loc = "/Users/Viii/Anaconda3/envs/rstudio/lib/R/library")
```

But when I replace that with `elasticnet`, it doesn't work.

And it gives me the error message saying

> "RRuntimeWarning: 'package 'lars' was installed by an R version with
>   different internals; it needs to be reinstalled for use with this R
>   version'.

I also try to install `glmnet` instead, it also gives me the error message

```
en = importr('glmnet', robject_translations = d, lib_loc = "/Users/Viii/Anaconda3/envs/rstudio/lib/R/library")
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File , line 1, in  en =
>   importr('glmnet', robject_translations = d, lib_loc =
>   "/Users/Viii/Anaconda3/envs/rstudio/lib/R/library")
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Viii\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2-2.9.4-py3.6-win-amd64.egg\rpy2\robjects\packages.py",
>   line 453, in importr env = _get_namespace(rname)
>
> RRuntimeError: Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package
>   called 'glmnet'

The sessioninfo in R:

```
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /home/viii/anaconda3/envs/rstudio/lib/R lib/libRblas.so

locale:
[1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
[3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
[5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
[7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
[9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods [7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] elasticnet_1.1.1 lars_1.2        

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.0 tools_3.5.0    yaml_2.1.18
```

Comment: Did you specify a *lib_loc* in your attempted `importr("elasticnet")`?

Comment: @Parfait yes I did exactly the same as I load PLS

Comment: Are you running Python in a virtual environment that cannot see your local CPU environment: [Determine if Python is running inside virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871549/determine-if-python-is-running-inside-virtualenv)?

Comment: @Parfait Hi, I followed the post and it says I am outside virtualenv.

Comment: Open R and just run `library(elasticnet, lib.loc="<same path>")`. Then print out `sessionInfo()`. Edit your above post with results. Let's see if `elasticnet` imports other packages it depends on.

Comment: @Parfait And I got an error message saying "RRuntimeWarning: 'package 'lars' was installed by an R version with different internals; it needs to be reinstalled for use with this R version'. But I just install this package today...

Comment: @Parfait Because elasticnet depends on lars, so I also import lars = importr('lars', lib.loc=<>), and then it gives me this error message in the middle and also ended with Error in loadNamepace(name): there is no package called 'lars'.

Comment: Is the `sessionInfo` run after `library(elasticnet, lib.loc="<same path>"`)? Please explicitly specify path. You may have multiple installations of *elasticnet* and *lars* across all `.libPaths()` but `rpy2` only sees one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47003754/1422451.

Comment: @Parfait Yes, and when I check .libPaths() there is only one path or my R.

Comment: You might have two different R versions installed on machine. Compare home paths: 1) run this in R: `R.home()` and 2) run this in Python: `from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr; base = importr('base'); print(base.R_home())` (semicolons mean different lines).

Comment: @Parfait Yes! In R it gives me "C:/Users/viii/ANACON~1/envs/rstudio/lib/R", but in python it gives "C:/Users/viii/Anaconda3/lib/R". I remember I installed spyder via Anaconda-Navigator and then I also install Rstudio here, but it says that it cannot be installed in the same environment and asked me to create a new env. Is this the problem? How should I solve it.

Comment: I am not familiar with Anaconda-Navigator. My recommendation is to install everything (languages and IDEs) outside of package distributions. And do not tie languages with any IDEs which should be installed afterwards separately. Also, your file paths do not align as they reflect Windows but your `sessionInfo` reflects Linux Ubuntu! You definitely have mismatched envs going on.

Comment: For a quick resolution, open the Rterm or R.exe at the rpy2 home path and run `install.packages("elasticnet")`. Like Python, R can run in terminal, not just RStudio.

Comment: @Parfait, Thanks! Could you explain more about the quick solution (sorry I am pretty new to this)? What do you mean by "at the rpy2 home path"?

Comment: In your terminal, start R at select location: `C:/Users/viii/Anaconda3/lib/R/R.exe` (rpy2 home). Then install packages(s).