# Unable to install R packages after installing Anaconda

Tags: r, jupyter

I have always work with R in RStudio and never had problem to install packages. I have recently installed Anaconda to use Jupyter Notebook for a collaborative project. However, when using R in Jupyter notebook, I am unable to install packages other then those in `r-essentials`. The problem seems to come from the R installed by Anaconda. When I try

```
install.packages("cubature", repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')
```

in its R console, I receive the following error

```
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://cran.us.r-project.org/src/
contrib:
  internet routines cannot be loaded
Warning message:
package ‘cubature’ is not available (for R version 3.4.1)
```

Following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34705917/conda-how-to-install-r-packages-that-are-not-available-in-r-essentials), I tried to "add new package to the correct R library used by Jupyter", but I receive the same error. I tried to install the package from Github, but I needed `devtools`, which is not in `r-essentials` and needs therefore to be installed to. I also tried to import R package with `rpy2` as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46140624/unable-to-install-r-package-in-python-jupyter-notebook), but the kernel simply died.

I still don't have anyway problem installing package with RStudio though. My (problematic) R version is

```
>R.Version()
$platform
[1] "x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0"
$arch
[1] "x86_64"
$os
[1] "darwin13.4.0"
$system
[1] "x86_64, darwin13.4.0"
$status
[1] ""
$major
[1] "3"
$minor
[1] "4.1"
$year
[1] "2017"
$month
[1] "06"
$day
[1] "30"
$`svn rev`
[1] "72865"
$language
[1] "R"
$version.string
[1] "R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)"
$nickname
[1] "Single Candle"
```

Any suggestions? Thx for your help!

Comment: Where did you get the "cran.us.r-project.org" URL from? is there a reason you are using that particular repo? And it's odd the error message is missing the "-" in the URL. Maybe a typo?

Comment: I got if from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34705917/conda-how-to-install-r-packages-that-are-not-available-in-r-essentials). In fact, I tried many other URL, but it did not seem to help. And yes, the "-" was a typo. My (edited) mistake.

Comment: If you try other URLs do you still get the exact same error message: "internet routines cannot be loaded"? How exactly did you install R in the first place?

Comment: Yep, exactly the same error message with others URL, like for example `install.packages("cubature", repos = 'http://cran.uk.r-project.org')`. R is installed with Anaconda when you install it. I tried to uninstall and reinstall Anaconda, but nothing changes.

Comment: I couldn't replicate your problem. If you are on a Mac/Linux, could you run `which r` to confirm which distribution of R you are running in the console.

Also you could try to reinstall r with `conda install -f r-essentials` and see what happens.

Comment: Still the same error message after `conda install -f r-essentials`. With `which r` I get `/Users/nicot/anaconda/bin/r`.

Comment: I uninstalled completely Anaconda and run `which r` and got `/usr/local/bin/r`. After reinstalling Anaconda 4.4.0 for Python 3 from [here](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#download), I still have the same error message and `which r` give me `/Users/nicot/anaconda/bin/r` back again.

Comment: Ok, I uninstalled Ananconda, RStudio and R. I then reinstalled *only* Anaconda for Python 3.4 from [here](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#download) and I run `conda install r-essentials` as suggested [here](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/use-r-with-conda.html). Same error message `Installing package into ‘/Users/nicot/Library/R/3.4/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning message:
“unable to access index for repository https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib:
  internet routines cannot be loaded”Warning message:
“package ‘cubature’ is not available (for R version 3.4.1)”`

Answer (score 0):

You can update r packages within RStudio via the Packages tab in the bottom-right (next to Files, Plots, etc.).
[image: Rstudio screenshot]