# Importing your R module in python scripts

Tags: python, r, python-import

Let say I have script calc.R with a function add.

```
add <- function(x, y) {
  return(x+y)
}
```

Is it possible to import 'add' in a python script test.py ?

(Had calc been a py script I could simply: from calc import add. Is there a soltuion for calc.R ?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R, Python: install packages on rpy2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561258/r-python-install-packages-on-rpy2)

Comment: gives me  rpy2.rinterface.NULL when trying to install an R script as a package.

Comment: I have the solution, you may open question for me to answer in a descriptive way.